# C# Error on Deploy IIS 7: "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'. Remove one definition."

Tags: c#, linq, iis, gridview

The goal is to populate a gridview with linq. The code works perfect on Visual Studio, but when deployed in IIS 7, occurs the error: "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'. Remove one definition."

I´m using the property DataSource in server side to populate, and not use the property DataSourceId.

The code from page aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

The code from .cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Initialize();
            }
        }

        protected void Initialize()
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }

        protected void LoadGrid()
        {
                dbDataContext dbDataContext = new dbDataContext();


                var entity =
                        from
                            p in dbDataContext.PRODUCTs
                        where
                            p.FL_ACTIVE == true
                        orderby
                            p.DT_CREATION
                        select p;

                GridView1.DataSource = entity;
                GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Adicional information:

Windows 7 running IIS v7.5

Application Pool running .NET Framework 2.0.50727

The project is developed with .NET framework 3.5

The error is occurring due to configuration IIS 7?

Answer (score 0):

Search using Ct+shif+F in entire solution using Id="GridView1", It might be at some other place.